# Node.js get value from php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I'm coding a discord bot
and I want to get the text of my bot's status from my database so I created a PHP file

```
<?php

$servername = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "bot";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

$username = "phph";

$query = "SELECT text FROM bot WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $text = $row['text'];
}

echo $text;

?>
```

I get the echo of $text when I execute the PHP file with XAMPP

now I want to know that how can I get the value of $text from PHP to JavaScript

help me please ;(

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">var x = "<?php echo $text ?>" </script>` So this isn't working?

Comment: is there a specific reason you don't just make the MySQL request inside your node.js app? This seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Comment: I don't make the MYSQL request inside my node.js is because I'm a noob in this I search a lot of informations on the Internet and all of them seems to be very complicated to me

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">var data = "<?php echo $text ?>" </script>` or you can pass data to a function like `<script type="text/javascript">printData("<?php echo $text ?>"); </script>` make sure function will be loaded before this action/line

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important programmer skills is the division of complex problems into small parts.

I understood that in your case you have `php` application that returns text on execution and you need to get this text in node js.

So if you run:

```
$ php app.php
```

you will see:

```
some text of Discord message
```

and you want to import this text into a variable in node js.

There are two possibilities:

1. Get this text on start on node js program

Then create `app.js` with

```
console.log(process.argv[2])
```

And type

```
$ node app.js example
```

You will see `example` so `example` can be accessed as `process.argv[2]`

So it is enough to type

```
$ node app.js `php app.php`
```

to have access to `some text of Discord message`

---

2. You can want to use php script output in node js when node js process runs.

In this case, read docs of child process

- https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node
- https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/

and in the future please divide your problem into smaller pieces like in this case:

"How to get the result of the command in node js"

without the context of discord, php and Xampp.

Comment: this is a good answer, but i think its better to call the PHP file as an API so you can call it localy from the node.js more than once and also call other PHP files if needed.

Comment: If PHP is exposed to the network then it can be developed in a microservices architecture. I recommend to the author can discuss the wider context of his solution on any forum devoted to architecture design patterns like: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/